# Why does this code print "IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted"?

Tags: java

```
public class Test {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            doSomething();
        } catch (Throwable t) {
            System.out.println("Caught exception: " + t);
        }
    }

    private static void doSomething() {
        try ( Resource r = new Resource(); ) {
            throw new SecurityException("deliberate exception");
        }
    }

}

class Resource implements AutoCloseable {
    public void close() {
        System.out.println("close()");
    }
}
```

I expect to see "SecurityException: deliberate exception", but instead I see "IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted".

My googling tells me that this happens when there is an exception thrown inside the try block, and then another exception is thrown by the close() method. But as you can see, this is impossible. Fortunately I can get the real exception from .getCause(), but I wish I could understand this behavior.

Openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18

Edit: I am running this in vscode. Beginnging to think this is a bug in its JVM. Will try a different javac and JVM later today. Thank You.

Edit: Doesn't matter what kind of exception I throw. Doesn't matter whether it is a checked exception or not. Always "Self-suppression". I used "SecurityException" to illustrate that sometimes it is important to be able to tell what type of exception was thrown.

Edit: Stack trace is Caught exception:

```
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
    java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Self-suppression not permitted
        at 
    java.base/java.lang.Throwable.addSuppressed(Throwable.java:1072)
        at jLib.Test.doSomething(Test.java:19)
        at jLib.Test.main(Test.java:7)
    Caused by: java.lang.SecurityException: deliberate exception
        at jLib.Test.doSomething(Test.java:18)
        ... 1 more
```

Comment: Try throwing a different kind of exception. I *suspect* this is because you are triggering the default [`SecurityManager`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/SecurityManager.html). But that isn't something typically done.

Comment: Works in Java 12: https://ideone.com/UpDgl2

Comment: Also works with Oracle JDK 17.0.1 and 17.0.7

Comment: I think this is not reproduceable, so probably something wrong with your code but not this specific snippet you posted here.

Comment: Also works in Java 18.

Answer (score 0):

I put the same code into ReplIt -- https://replit.com/@carl26/Java#Main.java -- and it throws the SecurityException I expect. Java -version there is "openjdk version "17.0.5" 2022-10-18".

So it is something about my particular JDK or JRE. I don't care because I now know that I was not coding it wrong, and because this problem is just an irritation that will probably go away by itself as I naturally update over time.

Thanks to the commenters who tried it on their JVMs and gave me the clue I needed.